# Reading CVS Files and Header value depending on Criteria I set

Tags: csv, groovy

Hi I am very new To Groovy scripting and Jmeter. I want to read CVS files depending the row criteria value. Below is the sample CSV file

> Criteria,Description,LabBookCode,FormulaType
>   Valid_Test_Data,Formula_Created_API_Testing,API Testing_Lab_12345,FML
>   Invalid_Test_Data,Formula,TestLAB,FMLLL

Depending on criteria I I pass like `Criteria = Valid_Test_Data`, Header Value of CSV should be set the respective row value like for `Valid_Test_Data` criteria first row values should be set. and for `Invalid_Test_Data` criteria second row value should be set to Header values of Description,`LabBookCode,FormulaType`.

any time If I use `${Description}` or `${LabBookCode}` variable in JMeter, row value should be fetched depending criteria I pass.  Column are not fixed will vary depending on the CSV files

Thanks for the help

Comment: what have you done so far? what method you are using to read csv file? please share your code.

Comment: I am unable to only identify first line from CSV i.e. headers to put it in Array

Comment: String testdatafile = new File(Test_Data_Preferences.csv").getText('UTF-8');
def reader = new StringReader(testdatafile);

def headers=null
reader.splitEachLine(','){line->
    line=line.collect{it.trim()}
    if(headers==null){
        //convert headers array to [name:index] map
        headers = line.withIndex().collectEntries();
        log.info(headers.toString());}
else{
      
        if( line[ headers['Criteria'] ]=='default_prefrences' ){
            log.info(line[ headers['Calender_View'] ]); 
        }

}

Comment: please add the code into the question. because in comments you can't format it.